# How to exit cordova app only on specific component

Tags: angular, cordova

I wanted cordova app made with angular to exit only if it is on login page. I googled it and found some code which exists the app if back button is clicked.

This is the code i have on index.html within script tag.

```
document.addEventListener('backbutton', function(event){
  event.preventDefault(); // EDIT
  navigator.app.exitApp(); // exit the app
});
```

But this will exit the app if back button is clicked, as expected.
What I wanted was to exist the app if it is only on login component, which I have searched for it and found nothing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, not all OS support navigator.app.exitApp(); - if im not mistaken, iOS doesn't support it.

I don't want to copy paste other peoples code, but if you are happy with that app only exists on Android on back button click - take a look at this OLD library - i still use it for my cordova projects:

https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=cordova

Specially on nova.application.js - and investigate how they handle the back event.